# Asp.net MVC unable to find view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem that My Asp.net MVC Application unable to find view, although it goes to the controller but the view can not be searched.

here is my folder structure:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I want to stick with this folder structure so I need a solution without changing of folder structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `Index.cshtml` inside a folder called `Login`. The engine looks for a folder with the same name as the controller's and a view with the same name as the action's. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to stick with this folder structure so I need a solution without changing of folder structure. 

How can i do that?

Thanks